# Fastest way to input huge strings?

Tags: c++, string, parsing, input

I have to read huge lines of strings from `stdin` so time is a critical issue. Strings are on consecutive lines and have no spaces so I can simply use  `while(cin>>str) { //code }` but this is extremely slow. I have heard that scanf is much more faster than cin but if I use  `scanf("%s,str)` I think that str is treated as `char*` and not a C++ `string` so I can't use the STL.  I could take input as char* and copy all the chars into  a C++ string but IMO that will also be slow.

Is there a way to get input using scanf or something but still get a C++ string as a result?

Comment: Profile both, then decide.

Comment: STL strings have a constructor to generate from C strings.

Comment: isn't scanf absolutely blacklisted as surefire buffer overrun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the average or maximum size of the text, you create `std::string` with a pre-allocated size.  One area occupying a lot of time is the memory (re) allocation by `std::string`.

Comment: how do i do that? i know the max size is 200000 characters but i don't want to fill the string while initialization. Should I use string::resize ??( And if after doing that i erase the string and want to reuse it should i use resize again or will the memory size be preserved. i am using string::clear to erase it.)

Comment: i think i got it. `string::reserve` should be used. but as i asked, after i delete string using `string::clear` and want to reuse it, should i type 'string::reserve` again?

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> str` is the closest thing you'll find in STL to `scanf("%s, str")`. The only reason `scanf` would be faster than `cin` is because it would be giving you a `char*` instead of a string, and while you can create a new string from the `char*` by just passing them in to the `string()` constructor, that would be almost the same thing as using `cin >> str`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
for (std::string line; getline(std::cin, line); ) {
  do_something_with(line);
}
```

I don't know if it is any faster than `cin >> line`, but it might be, since it doesn't need to deal with whitespace other than newlines. But I don't believe this is as significant as the overhead of sentry construction.